# Image load issue with custom page template on Internet Explorer

Tags: theme-development

I have created a website http://demo.tennis-florida.com/ and it is using custom theme that I built when I am opening this on Internet explorer.

- Images in custom post grid are not showing up (perfectly showing up in source code) but they are working fine with other browsers.
- On internet explorer 8 and below the main slider is displaying in
  half.

Comment: Ya, that is IE. Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22679433/1908141) I've done on SO

Comment: While this isn't anything to do with WordPress, I quickly browsed the site in IE8, 10, and 11, and could not find any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: You probably did some settings wrong with the slider or the slider is messed up because your pictures get totally skewed by it.

About your Problems:
1.: auto is not a valid value for the HTML Attribute "height" for images. Remove it completely from the image tags, and it will be sized "auto". So, no

```
<img class="alignleft wp-image-78 size-full" src="http://demo.tennis-florida.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/summer-camp-28.jpg" alt="summer-camp-28" width="100%" height="auto" />
```

but

```
<img class="alignleft wp-image-78 size-full" src="http://demo.tennis-florida.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/summer-camp-28.jpg" alt="summer-camp-28" width="100%" />
```

2.: Internet Explorer 8 and below don't understand HTML5 Tags like

```
<header></header>
<footer></footer>
```

and stuff. You need to use a polyfill to make it work.

Step 1: Go to https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv and download
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/master/dist/html5shiv-printshiv.min.js

Step 2: Save it in your theme folder.

Step 3: open your themes header.php and insert the following code in the head-section BEFORE the themes style.css:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/html5shiv-printshiv.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Step 4: Done!

Happy Coding,

Kuchenundkakao

Comment: Thanks a lot but slider issue is still present, is anything I can do with that ?

Comment: Which "Slider Issue" do you mean? The slider in IE8 works in full width for me...

Comment: When I use IE tab for firefox (Firefox adon, I don't know which IE version it renders) shows the slider image in half.
Here is an screenshot of the issue.
http://tinypic.com/r/2ns9a2v/8

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to use another slider. There are enough Sliders that have a responsive feature. Nevertheless, if it runs in IE>8, you should be satisfied. IE7 is not worth the hassle to make the website run in it.

Comment: Can you suggest one? which runs fine and do have a lot of "buy pro" kind of frustration ?

Comment: Well, i didn't use it myself (bc i built my own slider plugin, its just not ready for the wordpress plugins yet), but this uses the jquery cycle2 library, which is pretty good and can be used responsive: http://www.codefleet.net/cyclone-slider-2/